# How will i add an option under customizer the event calendar section?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-customizer

[image]

What is the customizer section name? I want to add a field option under customizer The Event Calendar section. Or how will I add a field under The Event Calendar option? Can someone help me with that?

```
`$wp_customize->add_section( 'the_event_secction_name' , array(
        'title'    => __( 'My Section Name', 'starter' ),
        'priority' => 30
    ) );   

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'starter_new_setting_name' , array(
        'default'   => '#000000',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Header Color', 'starter' ),
        'section'  => 'the_event_secction_name',
        'settings' => 'starter_new_setting_name',
    ) ) );`
```

Answer (score 0):

While in the Customizer preview, right-click on `The Events Calendar` section and inspect it, you'll get it's `id`.
As an example, if you right click on `Site Identity` section and inspect it, you'll have at the beginning the following :

```
<li id="accordion-section-title_tagline"...
```

So, the `id` **IS ONLY** `title_tagline`
Hope this helps